# Unit testing Backbone.Marionette listeners

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

I'd like to check what listeners are attached to my Marionette component, for example to the controller:

Example code of the component:

```
var MyController =  Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function () {

        this.listenTo(OtherModule, "start", function () {
            // something happens here
        });
        this.listenTo(OtherModule, "stop", function () {
            // something happens here
        });

    })
});

var myController = new MyController();
```

Example code of the unit test:

```
describe("MyController", function () {
    it("should have 2 listeners registered", function () {
        // ?
    });
});
```

I can trigger the events and see if the function I wanted to use was executed with the use of the jasmine's `spyOn` method, but I'm curious if there's a list of attached events available directly on the component.

How can I check what is my component listening to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're approaching unit testing in the wrong way - [unit tests should check that your object interacts with the outside world in the expected way. They shouldn't be concerned with implementation details](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/testing-on-toilet-test-behavior-not.html) (like the exact number of event listeners an Object has).

Having said that, you can use the `_listeners` (Backbone 1.0.x) or `_listeningTo` (Backbone 1.1.x) property:

```
var controller = new MyController;

describe("MyController", function () {
    it("should have 2 listeners registered", function () {
        expect(Object.keys(controller._listeners).length).toEqual(2)
    });
});
```

[Source](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-128) - `Marionette.Controller` extends `Backbone.Events`, which [stores listeners](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-29) in that property.

I wouldn't use this approach in a unit test, but it can be very useful for debugging memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I want to test the implementation details to double check, that the event handlers which I've registered have correct names. I found myself to have bugs after code refactoring where the event names changed, I believe such tests will remind me to check the names once again. I'd be glad to find a better method, have you encountered anything similar before?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to debug this kind of thing I often use a window.MyController = MyController. Then in the console I can save window.MyController and play around with it.

It looks like it will show the objects it's listeningTo but I'm not necessarily seeing what events it's tied to in this fashion. Anyway might be a look see. I'm also using Chrome so Firebug in Mozilla might give better info.